# Angular service error when I referenced from controller

Tags: angularjs, authentication, controller, angular-services

I tried to make a module for login. I defined a cotroller, I tried to acces function from a service and I received the an ReferenceError:

> ReferenceError: Auth is not defined

Controller:

```
class NavbarController {
  constructor($location) {
    this.$location = $location;
    this.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;
    this.isAdmin = Auth.isAdmin;
    this.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;
  }

  isActive(route) {
    return route === this.$location.path();
  }
}

angular.module('rideSharingApp')
  .controller('NavbarController', NavbarController);
```

Service:

```
(function() {

function AuthService($location, $http, $cookies, $q, appConfig, Util, User) {
  var safeCb = Util.safeCb;
  var currentUser = {};
  var userRoles = appConfig.userRoles || [];

  if ($cookies.get('token') && $location.path() !== '/logout') {
    currentUser = User.get();
  }

  var Auth = {
    isLoggedIn: function(callback) {
      if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role');
      }

      return Auth.getCurrentUser(null)
        .then(function(user) {
          var is = user.hasOwnProperty('role');
          safeCb(callback)(is);
          return is;
        });
    }
  };

  return Auth;
}

angular.module('rideSharingApp.auth')
  .factory('Auth', AuthService);

})();
```

I don't know why I received that error. I don't know very well angular, so can you help me to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797009/auth-is-undefined-ui-router-auth0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the "**Auth**" Dependency in the "**NavbarController**"...
Pass Auth in the constructor of the Controller.... Hope it'll solve the problem...

Thank You